# android shortcut isn't installed

Tags: android, shortcut

I have created app shortcut on home screen, but Its not working. it always shows the toast app isn't installed.

I have MainFragmentActivity and Fragment

this is Fragment Class

```
Intent shortcutIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_MAIN);
shortcutIntent.addCategory(Intent.CATEGORY_LAUNCHER);
shortcutIntent.setClassName(getActivity(),this.getClass().getName());
shortcutIntent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK | Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_RESET_TASK_IF_NEEDED);


Intent intent = new Intent();
intent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_SHORTCUT_INTENT, shortcutIntent);
intent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_SHORTCUT_NAME, getResources().getString(R.string.app_name));
intent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_SHORTCUT_ICON_RESOURCE,
Intent.ShortcutIconResource.fromContext(getActivity(), R.drawable.icon));
intent.putExtra("duplicate", false);
intent.setAction("com.android.launcher.action.INSTALL_SHORTCUT");

getActivity().sendBroadcast(intent);
```

this is Manifest

```
<uses-permission android:name="com.android.launcher.permission.INSTALL_SHORTCUT"/>
<uses-permission android:name="com.android.launcher.permission.UNINSTALL_SHORTCUT"/>
```

I have tried my app at emulator with api 19.
Any help will be appreciated. plz!!!!

Answer (score 0):

```
private void addShortcut() {

    //Adding shortcut for MainActivity
    //on Home screen
    Intent shortcutIntent = new Intent(getApplicationContext(),
            MainActivity.class);
    shortcutIntent.setAction(Intent.ACTION_MAIN);
    Intent addIntent = new Intent();
    addIntent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_SHORTCUT_INTENT, shortcutIntent);
    addIntent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_SHORTCUT_NAME, getString(R.string.app_name));
    addIntent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_SHORTCUT_ICON_RESOURCE,
           Intent.ShortcutIconResource.fromContext(getApplicationContext(),
                    R.mipmap.ic_launcher));
    addIntent.setAction("com.android.launcher.action.INSTALL_SHORTCUT");
    getApplicationContext().sendBroadcast(addIntent);
}
```

Comment: If you use it inside fragment, then u should use getContext not getApplicationContext(), or use reference for activity and then getApplicationContext()

Answer (score 0):

in my case, adding this to manifest worked

```
 android:exported="true"
```

Now, from activity which you create the shortcut, goto manifest add this attribute for that activity.